# passing a parameter to route in from app.run() in a flask

Tags: python, flask

I am using flask server for download a file ,
i want to pass the file_path to function upload_file filepath parameter from start server method,
how can i pass filepath from app.run() method.

```
def start_server(get_param):
    host = get_param['host']
    port = get_param['port']
    file_path = get_param['file_path']
    print('\nhost :: ',host)
    print('port :: ',port)
    print('file_path :: ',file_path)
    if not os.path.exists(file_path):
        print('\n..file not found..\n')
        sys.exit()
    print('\nserver started...')
    Timer(1.0, download_request,args=[host,port]).start()
    Timer(5.0, start_shutdown_server,args=[host,port]).start()
    app.run(host=host,port=port,use_reloader=False)

@app.route('/<file_path>')
def upload_file(file_path):
    try:
        print("\nuploaded file....")
        print(file_path)
        return send_file('/home/einfochips/Desktop/android.tar.gz', as_attachment = True,   cache_timeout = 0)
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        return "file not found"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config_param = {}
    config_param["host"] = '127.0.0.1'
    config_param["port"] = 5000
    config_param["file_path"] = '/home/einfochips/Desktop/android.tar.gz'
    start_server(config_param)
```

how i can pass parameter filename from run???

Comment: means how i can use that??

Comment: what is the error you get? add traceback

Comment: i am not getting any error, but i don't know how to pass a dynamic file path not a static path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get config from `current_app`

```py
from flask import current_app
import sys
...
...

@app.route('/<path:req_path>')
def upload_file(req_path):
    try:
        print("\nuploaded file....")
        print(req_path)
        main_path = current_app.config['file_path']
        print(main_path)
        return send_file(main_path, as_attachment = True,   cache_timeout = 0)
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        return "file not found"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.config["file_path"] = sys.argv[1]
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000)
```

Comment: But by using this , i can not get parameter as a file_path in upload_file(file_path) , i want that.

Comment: where do you want to use it? your code is not using it? just printing

Comment: bro , i want to use it in my application in testing , in that i have to pass the file_path from main and according to file_path ,the file would downloaded , here i have post for only one file , but i want to download multiple files , so i don't want to change everytime change of file_path , manually , i just passed the list of files , once i get the solution for downloading a one file.

Comment: you can use `current_app.config['file_path'] + file_path`, like this and download. Instead of giving file path give directory path and get file_name from user then use `os.path.join(dir_path, file_path)`. You want to have static directory and dynamic file_name? right?

Comment: i don't want static directory , i want to provide update testing , and in that so many directories and so many files.

Comment: i just want that function  upload_file(file_path) get the file_path any how..

Comment: if i get the solution for one path , then i can go more dynamic file path.